# spring security saml metadata become http not https

Tags: metadata, saml, weblogic12c, adc

I had followed the SAML example to do, but when I found the metadata downloaded become http as follow while I used https://domain:443/App/saml/metadata to get it. The Location is http not https which cannot pass to ADFS to build the claim

```
<md:SingleLogoutService Location="http://domain:80/App/saml/SingleLogout" Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"/>
<md:SingleLogoutService Location="http://domain:80/App/saml/SingleLogout" Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"/>
<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</md:NameIDFormat>
<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient</md:NameIDFormat>
<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent</md:NameIDFormat>
<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</md:NameIDFormat>
<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:X509SubjectName</md:NameIDFormat>
<md:AssertionConsumerService Location="http://domain:80/App/saml/SSO" Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" isDefault="true" index="0"/>
<md:AssertionConsumerService Location="http://domain:80/App/saml/SSO" Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact" index="1"/>
```

And I had try using code mapping and also force it to https

```
<!-- Secured pages with SAML as entry point -->
<security:http entry-point-ref="samlEntryPoint" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/spring/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" requires-channel="https"/>
    <security:custom-filter before="FIRST" ref="metadataGeneratorFilter" />
    <security:custom-filter after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="samlFilter"/>
    <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
 <security:port-mappings>
    <security:port-mapping http="8080" https="8443"/>
    <security:port-mapping http="80" https="443"/>
</security:port-mappings>
</security:http>
```

My environment is using A10 ADC to hold the cert and the Application Server is Weblogic 12c

Can anyone help me? thanks a lot

Comment: did you ever figure this out? i am having the same problem. thanks!

Comment: @lostdorje by adding the following codes in the beginning of the page solves the problem     <script >
     var loc = window.location.href+'';
     if (loc.indexOf('http://')==0){
      window.location.href = loc.replace('http://','https://');
     }    
    </script>

Comment: thanks... it turns out for me my system.properties file was configured for http, not https. changing that fixed my problem.